# Gradle build testing fails all of my tests, but individual running does fine

Tags: java, unit-testing, gradle, intellij-idea, junit

I am adding unit test classes to production code, and I have told IntelliJ IDEA to use the Gradle tester. I run the tests independently, and they are passing. However, the Gradle `test` task fails with practically all of my tests failing.

I've tried setting the tester back to the platform tester in the settings, to no apparent change.

```java
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ChatTranscriptTest extends GeneralUnitTest {

    @Test
    public void testDiscordMessageSend() {
        GuildMessageReceivedEvent guildMessageReceivedEvent = testGuildMessageReceivedEvent();
        DiscordChatListener listenerUnderTest = new DiscordChatListener(mockPlugin);

        listenerUnderTest.onGuildMessageReceived(guildMessageReceivedEvent);

        assertServerBroadcast("<TestUser> Testing");
    }

    private GuildMessageReceivedEvent testGuildMessageReceivedEvent() {
        return new GuildMessageReceivedEvent(jdaMock, 0L, new MessageMock());
    }

    private void assertServerBroadcast(String broadcast) {
        Server targetServer = mockPlugin.getServer();

        verify(targetServer, atLeastOnce()).broadcastMessage(broadcast);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMinecraftMessageSend() {
        Player playerMock = new MockPlayer();
        AsyncPlayerChatEvent playerChatEvent = new AsyncPlayerChatEventTestImpl(playerMock);
        MainListener mainListener = new MainListener(mockPlugin);

        mainListener.onPlayerChat(playerChatEvent);

        assertDiscordMessageSent("**TestUser**: Testing");
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("ResultOfMethodCallIgnored")
    private void assertDiscordMessageSent(String message) {
        JDA pluginJDA = mockPlugin.getJDA();
        TextChannel targetTextChannel = pluginJDA.getTextChannelById(0L);

        verify(targetTextChannel, atLeastOnce()).sendMessage(message);
    }
}
```

This is one of my tests. It's just general behavior testing.

What could be going wrong?

Comment: The tests are not wrong. Why don't you tell us what is going wrong during testing, aka exceptions etc. Most likely the stuff you want to test is not running, aka no minecraft client or server.

Comment: Please provide the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).